# Creating and dropping a table during Laravel test

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I've created a trait using in my Laravel 5.6 app. The trait is called `Projectable`. This trait is meant to be used by Eloquent models. In order to test the trait, I wanted to create a `ProjectableStub` model to use in the tests. However, since this is an Eloquent model, it requires a table.

I wanted to simply create and drop a table just for testing. However, when I do this, it seems like something breaks regarding the `RefreshDatabase` functionality. To demonstrate, I am simply running two tests, both of which try to create a `Product` model with `id = 1`. Since the `RefreshDatabase` trait is being used, this should work fine. And, in the example below, it does:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Product;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Concerns\Projectable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class ProjectableTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        //$this->createStubTable();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function example_first_test()
    {
        factory(Product::class)->create(['id' => 1]);
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function example_second_test()
    {
        factory(Product::class)->create(['id' => 1]);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        //$this->dropStubTable();

        parent::tearDown();
    }

    private function createStubTable()
    {
        Schema::create('stubs', function ($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    private function dropStubTable()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('stubs');
    }
}

class ProjectableStub extends Eloquent
{
    use Projectable;

    protected $table = 'stubs';

    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

However, as soon as I uncomment the two lines so that the `stubs` table is created and dropped, I get a SQL error that a duplicate ID is being used:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Product;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Concerns\Projectable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class ProjectableTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->createStubTable();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function example_first_test()
    {
        factory(Product::class)->create(['id' => 1]);
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function example_second_test()
    {
        factory(Product::class)->create(['id' => 1]);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->dropStubTable();

        parent::tearDown();
    }

    private function createStubTable()
    {
        Schema::create('stubs', function ($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    private function dropStubTable()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('stubs');
    }
}

class ProjectableStub extends Eloquent
{
    use Projectable;

    protected $table = 'stubs';

    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

> 1) Tests\Feature\ProjectableTest::example_second_test
>   Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Does anyone know why creating and dropping a table within the test is causing this issue? Is there a better way to go about this? Maybe some way to add a migration at runtime for this new table?

Comment: Can you explain a little more why you need to create this table for your tests if it doesn't exist otherwise?

Comment: @RossWilson it's because I'm trying to test the core functionality of the trait itself, not the way it's used within any specific model. In other words, different models will use this trait, and they will each specify different settings that effect the actions the trait performs for those specific models. I plan to write tests for each model using the trait separately. My intent here was to write tests for the core functionality of the trait and all the different ways it may be used.

Comment: I added the `ProjectableStub` model at the bottom of the test. That's the model I'm creating and using with the actual tests. However, you can see within the example tests I'm just using a different `Product` model to demonstrate the issue. It seems like something about creating and modifying a table during the test is effecting the `RefreshDatabase` functionality, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 6):

I think this might be the answer:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html

Creating a table is causing the active transaction created by `RefreshDatabase` to be automatically committed.

Making the stubs table temporary did the trick. It also means I don't need to drop the table either, since it happens automatically:

```
Schema::create('stubs', function ($table) {
    $table->temporary();
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Seems to be working perfectly so far.